# Clique em windows form transparente C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um windows form transparente para desenho sobre outras telas. Para a transparência, eu usei o seguinte código:

```
BackColor = Color.Red;
TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
```

Funcionou durante um tempo, porém agora ele não reconhece os cliques sobre a tela, é como se estivesse clicando através dela. Coincidentemente ou não, parou de funcionar depois de uma atualização do Windows 10, e funciona em outros computadores.

Não foi uma modificação no código que fez isto deixar de funcionar, porque mesmo voltando para versões anteriores do projeto, em que o clique era reconhecido, não funciona mais. Existe alguma outra forma de fazer a transparência da janela? Segue um print do programa, para que possam entender do que se trata a aplicação.

[image: Print da aplicação aberta sobre o navegador]

Comment: Só postando o código pra gente poder verificar.

Comment: O código da parte de transparência está aí :)

Comment: Eu acabei de criar um _form_ transparente e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Este código fica dentro do método construtor do único form. Dentro deste form, existe um painel onde são desenhado as coisas. Os eventos capturados são cliques do mouse, e são capturados na classe do painel. Porém, a minha questão não é como resolver este código, e sim outra maneira de fazer a transparência de um form.

Comment: Se você criou um form transparente que funciona da maneira que preciso, por que não posta como uma resposta?

Comment: Porque eu usei exatamente o código que tem na sua pergunta (????)

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você está fazendo isso da maneira errada, o jeito certo seria usando um overlay.

Comment: Ok, e eu vim aqui perguntar certamente porque eu tenho um código funcional. Obrigada pela sua ajuda, jbueno, tudo que eu precisava era de alguém que testasse e dissesse que funciona o que foi feito aqui. Com certeza a aplicação vai se sentir motivada com as suas palavras e começar a funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comportamento que você descreve é o esperado, como você pode ver na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When the TransparencyKey property is assigned a Color, the areas of the form that have the same BackColor will be displayed transparently. Any mouse actions, such as the click of the mouse, that are performed on the transparent areas of the form will be transferred to the windows below the transparent area.

Traduzindo

> Quando uma cor é atribuída a propriedade TransparencyKey, as áreas do formulário que possuem a mesma cor de fundo serão exibidas de forma transparente. Quaisquer ações do mouse, como um click do mouse, que forem executados na área transparente do formulário serão transferidas para a janela atrás da área transparente.

Em testes que fiz aqui, se eu usar Vermelho como `BackColor` e `TransparencyKey` eu tenho o mesmo comportamento que você descreve no Windows 10 de 64 bits, onde eu ainda não instalei a ultima atualização, já em uma maquina virtual rodando o Windows 7 SP1 ele funciona como descrito na documentação.

Como teste eu alterei a cor para Magenda e então no meu Windows 10 passou a se comportar como a documentação descreve também.

Então eu diria que era algum bug que foi corrigido com a ultima atualização do Windows 10.

Comment: Pois é, só funcionou aqui com a cor vermelha mesmo, o resto das cores o clique não era capturado. Não tinha visto esta parte da documentação, mas eu já imaginava que era um bug, não faz sentido uma cor funcionar e todas as outras não. Mas funcionou do jeito que queriam com a cor vermelha, porque acreditar na estagiária que disse que daria errado, né? Enfim, você tem alguma sugestão de como fazer isso de outra maneira?

Comment: Ok, problema resolvido. Criei um form opaco por trás e ele faz com que os eventos de clique possam ser capturados.